# Control library for Mango - do we need different binaries for WP70/WP71?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Context:
We have a control library and want to release a Mango-compatible version. The library does not use any Mango-specific functionality.

After installing 7.1 SDK I found only one problem in the old code, which concerned the use of TemplateBinding in the ControlTemplate. Everything else just worked.

The library can be built for WindowsPhone or WindowsPhone71 targets. The (binary) code is nearly identical; the only important difference seems to be that the target is hardcoded in the dll file.

Now imagine the developer who installed the control library and wants to use it in his project. This project has to be targeted for either 7.0 or 7.1 environments. The control library is shown in the Add References dialog only when its target is compatible with the project target. (Can be bypassed by manually browsing for the dll file, but this is a subpar solution.)

Do you see any way how to produce a single control library dll file that could be used for both 7.0 and 7.1 targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not dependent on Windows Phone Mango features, then you can simply compile the DLL for 7.0 and reuse it in 7.1 projects. That would be the best solution.

Even though it is not listed in Visual Studio, for most older libraries the "Browse" procedure is standard.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. But the "Browse" procedure has its own set of problems. Take for example updates: By default the control dll gets copied side-by-side application dll. Most programmers will have problem to start using updated control dll. Even if they remove control dll reference and add the reference to the new dll, the project will stil use the old dll.

Comment: I see above a source of big problems. A much better solution would be to write somewhere into the Registry that the control dll is compatible with WP7.1. (Like it can be done for WP7.0.) However, I am not sure if this can be done. Shall investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing how the things are done by SVL Toolkit, the real solution seems to be editing the registry key HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Microsoft SDKs. If you go down this key, then:

- Silverlight for Phone/v4.0/AssemblyFoldersEx lists assemblies for apps targeting WP7.0,
- Silverlight for WindowsPhone/v4.0/AssemblyFoldersEx lists assemblies offered for apps that target Mango.

You can refer the same assembly in both keys. This seems to override target hardcoded in the dll.

Have to test more to see if there are other caveats.